# Meaning of $θ$ asymptotic notation in equation when a variable tends to $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, asymptotics

I am trying to understand usage of $θ$ asymptotic notation for example in this equation $$e^x= 1+x+θ(x^2)$$ when $x\to0$.

Comment: Have look on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: What is "$*$" in your example - multiplication?

Comment: Typically $O$ is used instead.

Comment: @K.defaoite $\Theta$ and $O$ have different meanings. Incidentally, it's a capital $\Theta$, not a lower case $\theta$.

Comment: If $f(x)=h(x)+\Theta(g(x))$, there are a neighborhood of $0$ and two constants such that

$$c_0g(x)\le f(x)-h(x)\le c_1 g(x).$$

E.g.,

$$|x|<1\implies \frac13x^2\le e^x-1-x\le x^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x= 1+x+{x^2}/{2!}+ {x^3}/{3!}+.....$$

Thus $$\Theta (x^2) = {x^2} (1/2 +x/{3!}+....)$$

Note that $$ \lim_{x\to 0 } \Theta (x^2)/{x^2}=1/2$$ which is a constant.

Comment: $\Theta$ (note that it should be upper case) is better than $O$ here because it is more precise. The error term is "exactly quadratic", not just "at most quadratic".

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Thanks for the informative comment

Answer (score 1):

As we are considering case $x \to 0$, then we are in zeros [Deleted neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Deleted_neighbourhood), so, let's rewrite expression as
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1+\theta(x)$$
knowing, that limit of left side is $1$, the **most general** approximation notation for right side is any tending to zero function plus $1$. For this purpose is defined so call [little-$o$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) notation. So, in most general form, we can write
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1+o(1),x \to 0$$
i.e.
$$e^x= 1+x+o(x),x \to 0$$

And returning to $\theta$, if we understand under it [big-$\Theta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations), then, **more informative**, because on $\Theta(x)\subset o(1),x \to 0$, will be
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1+\Theta(x),x \to 0$$
i.e.
$$e^x= 1+x+\Theta(x^2),x \to 0$$.